# App Design and optimisation: graphing data

Tags: xcode, sqlite, cocoa, optimization, graph

Working in Xcode, Cocoa, Objective C

I m building an app which has an SQLIte database holding the data.  The data is a daily summary of about 6 float values over a period of potentially 40 years, although more usually 10 years.

I am writing routines which will graph the data into an NSview.  The user has several options in the UI as to whether to draw line or bar graph, the time period to graph, whether the data is weekly or daily etc.

There are two main functions to write here, one for updating the graph settings and one for getting data from the database in a form which the graph can handle (nested array of dates and values)

the question I have is whether it is best to load the full set of graph able data and have the graph 'decide' which slices of data to graph.  Or whether to submit multiple requests to the database each time the user selects an option.

For example, if the full set of graph able data were loaded, then if the user selects the weekly option, the graph drawRect method could simply iterate over each 7th entry in the array.  Alternatively, I could ask the database to re-submit an array of graph able data.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Why do you think that it is necessary to optimize?

Comment: Helpful question CL.  Partly it is about what makes best coding practice, partly because I thought making best use of resources was important (esp for iPhone/ipad).  It seems like it would be "cleaner" in a way to always fetch from the database, although that would not always be strictly necessary and seems wasteful(?)  At the same time having the graph view 'know' details of the model makes the graph view less re-useable.

Comment: CL - the reason we need to optimize is that if we don't, naively implemented code will far outstrip the progress of the hardware engineers.  Consider that Live Picture for the Classic Mac OS could composite and edit multiple 200 MB raster images on a 32 MB Mac Quadra.  But on my Mom's 1 GHz G4 iMac with 1.2 GB, there is quite a large lag when I resize an OpenOffice window.  It's not hard at all to implement an O(N^3) algorithm!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to select only the data you need, rather than letting the graph decide.

There's a lot more to consider than just the quantity of data you'll be reading.  There is also the number of memory allocations, how much memory will actually be used, and the memory that is used "behind the scenes" by the allocator.  There is also backing store paging.

Comment: Thank you Michael, thats helpful.